# How do I join same database name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Basically I do `while` two time to get main group & group value. Example

```
$group_query = $db->query("
        SELECT opt_id, opt_type 
            FROM ads_options 
            WHERE opt_id = '" . intval($data['ad_id']) . "'
            GROUP BY opt_type");
while ($group_data = $db->fetch($group_query)) {
    $option_query = $db->query("
        SELECT * 
            FROM ads_options 
            WHERE opt_id = '" . intval($data['ad_id']) . "' 
            AND opt_type ='" . $group_data['opt_type'] . "'
            ORDER BY opt_id DESC");
    while ($option_data = $db->fetch($option_query)) {
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Size   : S
         M
         L  
Color  : White
         Black
```

Question :

How to join current queries above with single statement?

**Update :**

Current database structure

```
opt_id  opt_type  opt_name  opt_price
1236    Size      S         0
1236    Size      M         1
1236    Color     Black     1
1236    Color     White     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would get the unique combinations, may be of help

```
$group_query = $db->query("
    SELECT
        DISTINCT opt_id, opt_type, opt_size
    FROM ads_options 
    WHERE opt_id = " . intval($data['ad_id']) . "
    ORDER BY opt_type, opt_size");
```

If you are able to supply more details as to precisely what you are trying to achieve, and the full design of ads_options, then it would be easier to provide more specific advice

Also a minor note, if opt_id is numeric then you don't need single quotes (') around it within the query (so removed them in example)

**EDIT**
Something like the following would return you a list of id, type, and then as third field a comma-delimited list of values, if that's of more help

```
$group_query = $db->query("
    SELECT
        opt_id, opt_type, GROUP_CONCAT(opt_name) AS opt_names
    FROM ads_options 
    WHERE opt_id = " . intval($data['ad_id']) . "
    ORDER BY opt_type");
```

For more information on GROUP_CONCAT check out this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

I've no idea if PHP programatically has something to help with this, I tend to use Coldfusion so if anyone knows of a PHP version of doing the following then that seems to match what OP was asking for

```
<cfoutput query="qryAdOptions" group="opt_type">
    #qryAdOptions.opt_type#
    <cfoutput>
        #qryAdOptions.opt_name#
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/11929-grouping-results-query#post50606 seems to suggest the following as potentially a match for the  I posted above so may be useful

```
$answer = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($results)) {
  if (!isset($answer[$row["obj_type"]])) {
    $answer[$row["obj_type"]] = array();
  }
  $answer[$row["obj_type"]][] = $row;
}
```

You then iterate over $answer.  This would play nicely with

```
SELECT * FROM ads_options WHERE opt_id = ......
```

Comment: Thank you Simon.. lot of information on your answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: NP, your question happened to appear while I was waiting on tests :)

Comment: Ah so the price is an id that links elsewhere, makes more sense